# How to copy all tables, stored procedures to another schema in Synapse data warehouse?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse

Currently, I need to transfer all tables (DDL and data in the tables), stored procedures to another schema in Synapse data warehouse. I checked the documentation below, but it seems that I have to move all of them one by one.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-schema-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Is there a method, command or query which I can transfer all the contents of a schema to another in Synapse data warehouse ?

Kind regards,

Comment: For problems like this, I use a SQL query to list all the objects and generate the require syntax around them. Then I copy paste that and run it. i.e. `select 'alter schema newschema transfer dbo.' + name from sys.tables`

Comment: Yeah good point @Nick.McDermaid, I guess it depends if 'transfer' means 'one way move, removing original from initial schema' (which your approach covers) or 'copy / duplicate' (which my proposed bulletpoints cover).

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid and wBob, your suggestions did point me to the right direction. There are scenarios which I need to transfer in one way move/removing original and copy/duplicate the contents of schema. Both of your input provided me a picture for the end to end solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in method to do this, but depending on your skills there are a number of different options:

- use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) built-in scripting options.  Newer versions of SSMS (v18.x and onwards) are capable of producing DDL for Azure Synapse Analytics.  Simply point to your object (table, stored proc, view etc) in Object Explorer, right-click it, and view the scripting options.  eg for tables you will see 'Script Table as'
- SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) - SSDT now has support for Azure Synapse Analytics, dedicated SQL pools.  So you can import your schema, do a find and replace in the .sql scripts in the project, and generate the script.  You can also use the Data Compare and Schema Compare features.
- command-line option `mssql-cli`.  This offers powerful command-line scripting options but you'll need to download and install it:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/mssql-cli?view=sql-server-ver15
- Use `CTAS` to transfer schema and data.  Create a simple CTAS template and run it for each of your tables:

  ```
   CREATE TABLE <new schema>.yourTable
   WITH
   (
       DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN,
       CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX
   )
   AS
   SELECT *
   FROM <old schema>.yourTable;
   OPTION ( LABEL = 'CTAS: copy yourTable to new schema' );
  ```

So a few options for you.